# Criar uma pasta com um determinado nome

Tags: java

Estou a tentar criar uma pasta com um determinado nome mas não sei porque aparece sempre bin+nome.

Exemplo:
Se secondArg = ponto então o nome da pasta fica binponto.

Será porque estou a correr no terminal? Visto que quando corro no terminal tenho de ir à pasta do projecto e depois ao bin para poder executar a class.
Como posso resolver?

```
private void makeDir(String secondArg) {
        File theDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + secondArg);

        // if the directory does not exist, create it
        if (!theDir.exists()) {
            System.out.println("creating directory: " + theDir.getName());
            boolean result = false;

            try{
                theDir.mkdir();
                result = true;
            } 
            catch(SecurityException se){
                //handle it
            }        
            if(result) {    
                System.out.println("Repository " + theDir.getName() + " was been created");  
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Em que lugar sua pasta deve ser criada?

Comment: Na pasta do projecto onde se encontra as pastas bin e src @FelipeMarinho

Answer (score 1):

Faltou um separador de pastas:

```
private void makeDir(String secondArg) {
        File theDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + 
 secondArg);

        // if the directory does not exist, create it
        if (!theDir.exists()) {
            System.out.println("creating directory: " + theDir.getName());
            boolean result = false;

            try{
                theDir.mkdir();
                result = true;
            } 
            catch(SecurityException se){
                //handle it
            }        
            if(result) {    
                System.out.println("Repository " + theDir.getName() + " was been created");  
            }
        }

 }
```

Utilizei [`File.separator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separator) ao invês de barras(`\` ou `/`) porque assim fica a cargo do sistema operacional em execução definir.

Comment: Assim guarda na pasta bin. Eu queria que ficasse na pasta do meu projecto onde se encontram as pastas bin e src @diegofm

Comment: @Rafael de qualquer forma essa correção é necessária no seu código. Ta usando eclipse?

Comment: Sim, estou a criar um client-servidor que caso o cliente insira um certo comando o servidor deve criar uma pasta com o nome dado pelo cliente. Não consigo usar o eclipse para correr o programa @diegofm

Comment: @Rafael mas sua aplicação vai rodar do eclipse? Porque não faz muito sentido configurar para abrir na pasta do projeto, sendo que depois que você gerar o jar, a referencia será perdida. Faça um teste, gere o jar ou copie o arquivo `suaClasse.java` e execute via cmd. Vai funcionar certinho.